# Unable to create Android Resource Directory for flavor in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a project with two flavors and decided to add a third. However with the third flavor I am experiencing some problems.

My res file is not defined as an Android resource file, and consequently my layout xml files are not rendered.

You can see the file res file for flavor len does not have the yellow mark on the bottom right like the one for en.

[image]

When I right click on the en-res folder I see the create resource file, however I do not see this for my len-res folder.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way I can tell studio my folder is a resource folder ?

I am running 0.3.7 on Windows

```
productFlavors {
    de {
        packageName 'org.rh.ellierides.de'
    }
    en {
        packageName 'org.rh.ellierides'

    }
    len {
        packageName 'org.rh.ellierides.en.lite'
    }
```

Comment: How did you add the third flavor? Did you click the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button after adding it, if you edited the build files by hand?

Comment: I changed the build Gradle file : see edit above. I copy pasted the en flavor and changed it. I also tried removing it and re-adding via a new folder. I did sync the Gradle files, I also tried restarting Studio

Comment: According to the release notes Issue 60729: Mark res folders as resource folders, was fixed in 0.35, but I cannot find how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by changing the build variant to the specific one which was causing me problems in my case len

Once I built this flavor the project self corrected.